# Outlook removes full domain name in email address. Can the properties be displayed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, properties, headers

When I receive forwarded messages in Outlook 2003, the email addresses are often truncated to just names. I know how to display the properties of those addresses contained in the message sent directly to me. But, multiple messages may be attached that have been forwarded to/from other individuals, and I can only see names in those attached/forwarded messages. Is there a way to expand the properties on those names to obtain the full email address?